# Why does System.Net.Http load all assembly names from the global assembly cache?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I'm trying to figure out why I can load the assembly name `System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` and `System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` from the global assembly cache.

I have .Net 4.7.2 installed, and I am loading the assembly like this:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
Console.WriteLine(assembly.GetName().FullName);// prints "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
```

From what I've read, there's nothing to indicate that loading an assembly from the global assembly cache ignores the version number when loading an assembly, so can anyone explain why .Net Framework sees these two different assemblies as equivalent?

Comment: So your question is "I asked for 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3', but I got 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0'", correct?

Comment: @paulsm4 that's right. In fact if I ask for any version of `System.Net.Http` from `4.0.0.0` to `4.2.9.9` I get given `4.0.0.0` from the GAC.

Comment: Are you sure the version (assembly version, not a file version) you are trying to load even exists? Pretty much all .Net Framework assemblies has fixed version that matches version of framework (x.0.0.0) to support inplace upgrade...

Comment: The other assembly names are referenced in some nuget packages. For example the System.Net.Http nuget package, which contains an assembly with version 4.1.1.3, or some versions of the Google compute client libraries which reference 4.1.1.2

Comment: Is there are reason why you are loading this dynamically and not playing assembly redirect football as usual?

Comment: @00110001 yes, this assembly has some odd effects if you put it into binding redirects. If you add a binding redirect with a target version that is not 4.0.0.0 then you get runtime bind failures, if you add a binding redirect with a target version that is 4.0.0.0 then you get build time warnings about conflicting assembly versions. The question above is the point I got to in my investigation of why this is happening.

Comment: @Ceilingfish it doesn't. Assemblies can't override .NET's redirection behavior. I suspect the real problem is a mess of binding redirects caused by .NET Standard compatibility libraries. Probably because your project used to target 4.x versions below 4.7. The best solution is to *remove* all redirects and let NuGet add them if needed. Even better, remove all `System.X` packages and only add them back if compilation fails

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes the answer for real projects is indeed to remove all binding redirects. However, this question is about why those assembly names are redirected. See my answer for more details on the cause of this problem.

Comment: Because .NET Standard compatibility packages added those redirects, not because of the Unification table. When you add a .NET Standard 2.0 package to a project that targets an older .NET version it adds a few direct dependencies and a TON of indirect ones, going right down to the core libraries. That's where things fail: it was all too common to end up with conflicting *in*direct dependencies that only appear when you try to run your application in production. On a Dev machine things worked because .NET would pick the GAC version as a fallback

Comment: You won't avoid this with dynamic loading. `System.Net.Http` is just one of the packages distributed outside the SDK. Dataflow, all the Microsoft.Extensions.* packages and many others are distributed through NuGet and would result in such versioning conflicts. You can't add dynamic loading calls for dozens of packages. And then, you have the third-party packages like Json.Net, Serilog, Dapper etc. Even *one* of them can result in a cycle of conflicting dependencies that can't be resolved by updating

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're quite right, the above program is just to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a partial answer to this question. This behaviour is the result of the .Net Framework Unification Table. This is a construct inside the .Net Framework runtime that has knowledge of a select number of assemblies, `System.Net.Http` being one of them.

I can't, however, find any documentation on this, or any way of finding out which assemblies are present in this unification table.

Comment: IIRC, HttpClient came from Web API 2,  which wasn't part of .NET Framework. It used to be delivered through NuGet, then got merged into the Framework around .NET 4.6, then came .NET Standard and then the versioning hell began. Those were not the times to stop sniffing glue.

Comment: +100 to what CodeCaster said, and you can't fix that mess by dynamically loading assemblies. Simply remove all `System.X` references PackageReference and binding redirects from your projects, then add back only those needed to avoid compilation errors. Few (if any) of the binding redirects are needed if your projects are compatible with .NET Standard

Comment: Doing a little more digging, I've found this announcement by MS on adding implicit support for .net standard libraries into .Net Framework. https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/514. I've reached out to them to see if they can clarify where I can get a list of the affected assemblies.